# How to add a new line to a stargazer() title?

Tags: r, newline, stargazer

I am printing descriptive statistics using stargazer().

```
stargazer(datdbb,out = "Summary.html",title = "Summary Statistics \\\\ 1970-1998")
```

I tried to add a new line to the title between Summary Statistics and 1970-1998 but unfortunately, it does not work. Does anyone know how to add a new line to the title?

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to have the line. Above the title?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. Between Summary Statistics and 1970-1998

Comment: Does adding `\n` not work?`

Answer (score 0):

```
stargazer(datdbb,out = "Summary.html",title = "Summary Statistics \\n\ 1970-1998")
```